# Diagonal matrix product $ADA^T$

Tags: matrices

Consider a matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ and a diagonal matrix $D$ of dimension $m$. Is there a way to simplify the product $ADA^T$?

Comment: For a case of $m=n$, there is almost no hope because we know that every symmetric matrix over a field can be written in form of $ADA^T$.